# UI not updating for bound element

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

My property updates just fine, but my user interface is not updated.
What am i doing wrong?

I also tried setting the `DataContext` not in XAML, but in the code behind constructor, but that didn't work either.

ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        TestCommand = new RelayCommand(UpdateTest);
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion

    private string _test;
    public string Test 
    {
        get { return _test; }
        set 
        { 
            _test = value; 
            NotifyPropertyChanged(); 
        }
    }

    public ICommand TestCommand { get; set; }

    public void UpdateTest()
    {
        Test += "test ";
    }
}
```

View:

```xaml
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Test}"  />
        <Button  Grid.Row="1" Content="Test 2" Command="{Binding TestCommand}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not implementing `PropertyChanged` correctly. The event model for .NET requires that the `sender` argument of the invoked delegates is set to the reference of the object actually raising the event. You set that value to `null`.  Your code should use `this` instead:

```
protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Note that for thread safety, you should also not use the "check and raise" pattern on the event field itself. You should instead store the field in a local variable, check the local variable, and then raise the event from that variable if non-null. The above, which uses the `?.` operator ("null conditional operator") effectively does this; the compiler generates the local variable implicitly for you and ensures that the reference won't change between the time you check it for `null` and the time you actually try to use it.

Comment: Thank you, that indeed did the trick. Can't believe i missed that :)